# Javascript immediate function and code scope

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I am confused about scope when comparing normal function and immediate function.
Here is a example:

```
var num=5;
var x=3;
 doubleNum = function(){
   num = num*x
   x++;
   return num;
};
console.log(doubleNum());//15
console.log(doubleNum());//60
console.log(doubleNum());//300
```

This is a normal function that num and x are defined globally and accessible by doubleNum, as a result num and x are updated.

```
var num=5;
var x=3;
doubleNum = function(){
   num = num*x
   x++;
   return num;
}();
console.log(doubleNum);//15
console.log(doubleNum);//15
console.log(doubleNum);//15
```

However if I define a immediate function and call it same way as above, I got different answer. Even I am expecting to have same output
Did I miss something essential? Or did I understand some concept wrong?
Please help. 
Thanks in advance.
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jccgadam/uqx1sos9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `doubleNum` is not a reference to the function, but keeps the result of an anonymous function call.

In the first case you assign to the `doubleNum` a function and every time calling it via `doubleNum()`, you change the outscoped variables inside it and return a `num`. You do this `3` times. Your code is equivalent something to like

```js
var num=5;
var x=3;

doubleNum = function(){
   num = num*x; // Every call will affect the outscoped num
   x++; // Every call will affect the outscoped x
   return num;
};

var val = doubleNum(); // Call changes the values and returs a new result
console.log(val);

val = doubleNum(); // Call changes the values and returs a new result
console.log(val);

val = doubleNum(); // Call changes the values and returs a new result
console.log(val);
```

In the second case you assign to the `doubleNum` the result of a **single call anonymous function**. The function value is already computed one time and assigns the result to the `doubleNum`. Your code is equivalent something to

```js
var num=5;
var x=3;
var doubleNum;

var myFunction = function(){
   num = num*x;
   x++;
   return num;
};

doubleNum = myFunction(); // Only one call

console.log(doubleNum);
console.log(doubleNum);
console.log(doubleNum);
```

Comment: `doubleNum` is a function right ? Probably a variable holding _anonymous function expression_

Comment: In the first example, it is a reference to the function. Not holding but refering

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation especially these two clear examples.Well answered my questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I miss something essential?

Just that in the **second case**, the value of `doubleNum` is already computed because the **function is invoked as soon as it is defined**.

On the other hand, in the first case only `function` definition was assigned to `doubleNum` rather than the result of its invocation.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate function call is being evaluated only once. You're allocating a value not an immediate function to doubleNum. To accomplish a similar effect, try using a class and getters.

```
class ClassName {
  constructor(){
    this.num = 5;
    this.x = 3;
  }
  get doubleNum() {
    this.num = this.num*this.x++;
    return this.num;
  }

}

var double = new ClassName();

console.log(double.doubleNum);//15
console.log(double.doubleNum);//30
console.log(double.doubleNum);//300
```